# how to sort my json data and load uitable view swift3?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode

how to load my json data and load uitable view im trying lots of time but no result found. this is my json tree

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

]

any one help me ? thanks advance

Comment: What you have tried show your code!

Comment: What have to done show ur code

Answer (score -2):

Convert code json to Array and then try this code.

```
  let sortedArray = sortArrayUsingKey(strKey: "id", unSortedArray:unsortarray)

 func sortArrayUsingKey(strKey:String,unSortedArray:NSArray) ->NSArray {

    var tempArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
    tempArray = unSortedArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray;
    let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: strKey, ascending: true);
    tempArray.sort(using: [descriptor]);
    return tempArray as NSArray;
 }
```